# I want to keep key in foreach condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I want to keep `$key` in my array, How can I do it in `foreach` loop?

```
foreach ($urls as $key=>$url){
        $live[] = file_get_contents($url);
    };
```

My key is important, when i used foreach loop, how can I keep `$key`? When i do like this `$live[] = file_get_contents($key=>$url);` in `foreach`. it give me error.

Should I need to use two foreach loop or I can use one loop?

```
 $live = array();
    foreach ($urls as $key=>$url){
        $live[$key] = file_get_contents($url);
    };
    foreach ($live as $key=>$url) {
        $live[$key] = json_decode($url);
    };
```

Comment: `$live[$key] = file_get_contents($url)` ??

Comment: You want to preserve the same keys in the `$live` array ?

Comment: Thanks so much. its worked for m @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya already done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpreting that you want to preserve the same keys in the `$live` array, as in your `$urls` array. Just use the $key from foreach loop, to assign values in the $live array. Do the following:

```
foreach ($urls as $key=>$url){
    $live[$key] = file_get_contents($url);
};
```

**Updated Question:** You can do in a single loop. Check the following:

```
$live = array();
foreach ($urls as $key=>$url){
    $live[$key] = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
}
```

Comment: Can you help me more one?

Comment: @KINNARI yeah! tell me

Comment: added in my question for more help?

Comment: yes its asking time to accept it. because i asked question... but i think updated answer will not work for me.. because ` $live[$key]['json_decoded'] = json_decode($url);` i want to pass ` $live = json_decode($live);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180383/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-kinnari).

Comment: hi are you online? @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: @KINNARI please join the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180383/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-kinnari